# Edição de imagens utilizando OpenCV sem funções prontas

Tags: c++, imagem, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, rgb

Tenho a seguinte imagem mostrada abaixo e preciso transformar ela em em cinza e depois binarizar ela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu utilizo o seguinte código para mostra-la na tela

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg");// Lê a imagem no local onde ela é gerada(matriz)
cv::namedWindow("RGB");
cv::imshow("RGB",img); //abre a imagem na janela do windows de nome olá mundo
int keyCode = cvWaitKey( ); // Manter janela ativa equanto nenhuma tecla for pressionada

return 1;
```

Mas preciso transformar essa imagem em cinza sem usar funções prontas como cvCvtColor ou cvThreshold, alguém poderia me ajudar me indicando pelo menos um artigo que trate do assunto ?

Answer (score 7):

Para fazer o que você precisa, basta percorrer os pixels da imagem usando a função [`Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at). Essa função permite acessar o valor de um pixel em uma dada coordenada `x` e `y`.

### Conversão para Cinza

A conversão para tons de cinza pode ser realizada de algumas formas diferentes. O jeito mais simples é com o método da média: você basicamente tira a média dos valores em cada banda de cor (vermelho, verde e azul) para obter um só valor de intensidade luminosa. Outro método um pouco melhor é o da extração do brilho. Neste método, você tira a média *apenas* do maior e do menor valor dessas bandas (ignorando assim aquela cor intermediária). Por fim, outro método é diretamente relacionado com a forma como os humanos percebem o mundo. As proporções empregadas nessa fórmula decorrem das proporções dos cones (células fotossensíveis na retina humana):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O método de média é praticamente o mesmo do método de brilho, e eles tendem a reduzir o contraste. O método de luminosidade funciona melhor de forma geral, tanto que é o método mais usado (inclusive nas ferramentas de edição, como o Gimp ou o Photoshop). Outro motivo pra ele ser utilizado é que o ser humano é mais sensível ao verde, e por isso essa forma de conversão geralmente gera imagens mais agradáveis à percepção humana.

### Imagem Binária

Sobre a limiarização (*thresholding*, o processo utilizado para criar uma imagem binária), esse é um processo igualmente simples. Basta processar todos os pixels e trocá-los para `0` (o equivalente a preto) ou `255` (o equivalente a branco) dependendo se eles forem acima ou abaixo de um limiar escolhido. A escolha de como fazer é uma convenção, mas costuma-se transformar em `0` se o valor for menor ou igual e transformar em `255` se for maior do que o limiar. A escolha do limiar é baseada no que se deseja fazer (por exemplo, separar objetos do fundo) e também da distribuição das cores na imagem (use o [histograma de cores](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/pt-br/tutorials/histograms2.htm) para fazer essa análise).

### Exemplos

Eis um código de exemplo que faz o que foi explicado:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

// Método da Média: Média dos valores das cores
uchar metodoMedia(Vec3b RGB)
{
    uchar azul = RGB.val[0];
    uchar verde = RGB.val[1];
    uchar vermelho = RGB.val[2];

    return (uchar) ((azul + verde + vermelho) / 3);
}

// Método do Brilho: Média dos valores máximos e mínimos das cores
uchar metodoBrilho(Vec3b RGB)
{
    uchar azul = RGB.val[0];
    uchar verde = RGB.val[1];
    uchar vermelho = RGB.val[2];

    return (uchar) ((std::max(std::max(azul, verde), vermelho) + std::min(std::min(azul, verde), vermelho)) / 2);
}

// Método da Luminosidade: Ponderação decorrente das proporções médias de cones no olho humano
uchar metodoLuminosidade(Vec3b RGB)
{
    uchar azul = RGB.val[0];
    uchar verde = RGB.val[1];
    uchar vermelho = RGB.val[2];

    return (uchar) ((0.21 * vermelho) + (0.72 * verde) + (0.07 * azul));
}

int main()
{
    // --------------------------------------------
    // Carrega a imagem original
    // --------------------------------------------

    Mat img = imread("lena.jpg"); // A imagem RGB carregada é CV_8UC3 porque tem três canais, as cores (R + G + B).

    int largura = img.size().width;
    int altura = img.size().height;

    // --------------------------------------------
    // Cria uma nova imagem em tons de cinza
    // (com o método de luminosidade)
    // --------------------------------------------

    Mat gray(largura, altura, CV_8UC1); // A nova imagem criada só tem 1 canal (CV_8UC1), a intensidade luminosa.

    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < largura; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < altura; y++)
        {
            Vec3b pixel = img.at<Vec3b>(x, y);
            uchar intensidade = metodoLuminosidade(pixel);
            gray.at<uchar>(x, y) = intensidade;
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------
    // Cria uma imagem binarizada
    // --------------------------------------------

    Mat bin(largura, altura, CV_8UC1); // Essa imagem também só tem 1 canal, de preto e branco.
    uchar limiar = 128; // Limiar utilizado.

    // O método é o seguinte:
    // Pixels com luminosidade abaixo do limiar se tornam "preto" (0), e acima se tornam "branco" (255).
    for(x = 0; x < largura; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < altura; y++)
        {
            Vec3b pixel = img.at<Vec3b>(x, y);
            uchar intensidade = metodoLuminosidade(pixel);

            if(intensidade <= limiar)
                bin.at<uchar>(x, y) = 0;
            else
                bin.at<uchar>(x, y) = 255;
        }
    }

    namedWindow("Imagem Original");
    imshow("Imagem Original",img);

    namedWindow("Imagem em Cinza");
    imshow("Imagem em Cinza", gray);

    namedWindow("Imagem Binária");
    imshow("Imagem Binária", bin);

    cvWaitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

O resultado desse código são as seguintes janelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apesar do método de luminosidade (aquele decorrente da percepção humana) ser o mais usado, nota-se que os outros métodos geram resultados bastante parecidos. Veja nos exemplos abaixo (eu não coloquei o código que gera essas imagens, mas basta usar os três métodos que existem no código anterior):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deve ser possível notar que a última imagem é mais escura (tem uma intensidade luminosa média maior) e também mais bonita (ainda que isso seja uma questão de opinião). Isso decorre do fato de se dar mais peso ao verde no método de luminosidade, tal como ocorre na percepção humana. Ainda assim, pode ser que exista algum uso em que os outros métodos sejam interessantes (quando se quer justamente reduzir o contraste entre o claro e o escuro na imagem).

> IMPORTANTE: Note no código (principalmente nas funções de conversão
>   para os vários métodos) que apesar de eu (e você) chamar o padrão de
>   três bandas de RGB (por causa do Red, Green e Blue), o OpenCV usa BGR
>   na manipulação de suas imagens!