# Algoritmo para detectar nudez com boa precisão

Tags: algoritmo, processamento-de-imagens

Estava pesquisando algumas bibliotecas em Python que pudesse detectar a nudez em fotos, para  que, de alguma forma, eu pudesse evitar conteúdo impróprio no meu site.

Daí encontrei a biblioteca [nudepy](https://github.com/hhatto/nude.py).

O problema é que, para algumas imagens, ele erroneamente retornava positivo, pois as imagens não continham nudez.

Por exemplo, a imagem abaixo (que não contém nudez), ao fazer o teste, retornou `True`.

Veja:

[image: Minka Kelly]

```
import nude

nude.is_nude('minka-kelly.jpg'); // True
```

O usuário [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) recomendou que eu fizesse testes com uma foto que tivesse apenas cor de pele. Já para essa imagem o resultado foi `False`.

Veja:

[image: Paleta de cores de pele]

Daí fiquei me perguntando qual era o critério utilizado para detecção de nudez.

Mesmo sabendo que isso pode ser falho, gostaria de ser esclarecido nos seguintes pontos:

- Existe algum algorítimo que detecte nudez com alto grau de eficiência?
- Qual é a técnica que costuma ser utilizada para detecção de nudez em uma imagem?

#Atualização:

Foram-me solicitados testes com imagens também com preto-e-branco, para avaliarmos a forma que o `nudepy` analisa as imagens.

Aqui vai o teste. Existem três imagens numa pasta (tirei o printscreen da tela)

[image: Analise de imagem com nudepy]

Ao rodar `nudepy *`, os seguintes resultados são retornados:

```
flor.jpg          False
minka-kelly.jpg   True
tom_cinza.jpg     False
```

Comment: Posta as imagens que ele acertou :D

Comment: Simples, se a imagem estiver sendo bem mais acessada que as outras, é sinal de alguma coisa :P

Comment: O algoritmo pode ser baseado em técnicas de machine learning e/ou de análise dos histogramas de cor. Mas isto é apenas o meu palpite.

Comment: A machine learning visa construir algoritmos que têm a capacidade de aprender e fazer determinadas previsões, sem serem explicitamente programados para tal.  Basicamente tais algoritmos visam construir um modelo a partir de exemplos (neste caso de nudez) que são introduzidos, para depois tomarem determinadas decisões em função desse modelo. Os algoritmos de reconhecimento de padrão, por exemplo, ou a pesquisa do google baseiam-se em técnicas de machine learning. Um histograma, por outro lado, é uma representação gráfica de uma distribuição estatística; neste caso, seria da cor.

Comment: É possível que possa haver algo comum no que diz respeito à distribuição da cor nesse tipo de imagens e o algoritmo basear-se nisso.

Comment: A resposta está aqui: https://sites.google.com/a/dcs.upd.edu.ph/csp-proceedings/Home/pcsc-2005/AI4.pdf?attredirects=0. Aparentemente é mesmo pela análise estatística da distribuição de cor. Não é nada mais sofisticado.

Comment: testou com fotos P&B?

Comment: Tem um paper bem legal sobre isso aqui: [Nude Detection in Video using Bag-of-Visual-Features](http://laplace.dcc.ufmg.br/npdi/uploads/bd254485-1735-d227.pdf)

Comment: WallaceMaxters você já testou com pessoas de diferentes tons de pele (do Negro ao Albino)? já testou Ambos os sexos? (Um homem sem camisa não é considerado nudez já uma mulher sim)? já testou fotos com alguma lateralidade?

Comment: @Ricardo o negro também é reconhecido como nudez. Creio que eu já tenha feito esse teste, dá certo também.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> **TL;DR**
>
> Mais de 90% de acurácia, como a biblioteca que você já usa aparentemente obtém (de acordo com o artigo que ela cita), é uma *ótima* precisão. Mais do que isso é pouquíssimo provável de se obter com tecnologia atual.
>
> E como você percebeu nos seus testes, a mesma foto que produz falso
>   positivo colorida não produz "erro" na versão em tons de cinza (não
>   confundir com preto e branco! PB é uma imagem binária, só com preto e
>   branco *literalmente*). Mas isso se deve ao fato de que a biblioteca usa
>   um modelo RGB. Então, ela só funciona para imagens coloridas.
>
> ---
>
> **Links Relevantes**
>
> ---
>
> 1. Em 19/04/2016 foi postado [este fantástico artigo](https://dev.to/clarifai/what-convolutional-neural-networks-look-at-when-they-see-nudity) sobre as abordagens
>      mais modernas na detecção de nudez, utilizando [*deep learning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning). Vale a 
>      leitura. Mas, aviso aos mais sensíveis: o artigo contém imagens com nudez.
>
> > Curiosamente, [muita gente não sabia](https://twitter.com/alexjc/status/722730449550897152) que a famosa [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) (eu já
> >     mencionei ela aqui em outras respostas), amplamente usada na Visão
> >     Computacional, é uma imagem com nudez. lol
>
> 2. A biblioteca *deepgaze* (disponível [no Github](https://github.com/mpatacchiola/deepgaze)) tem, entre outras
>      coisas bacanérrimas, detecção de pele por [retro-projeção (*backprojection*)](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html).
>
> ---

Esse tipo de detecção é efetuado sobre os dados de uma imagem digital, isto é, sobre os valores discretos de iluminação contidos nos pixels. E a dificuldade de "interpretação" tá justamente ai: o que pra você, humano, é uma pessoa usando um vestido é, para o computador, apenas uma matriz de valores inteiros representando amostragens de iluminação (em uma só banda, no caso de imagens em tons de cinza, ou mais bandas, como no caso de imagens RGB - uma banda para cada faixa do [espectro luminoso visível](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espectro_vis%C3%ADvel)).

Há diferentes abordagens para se trabalhar computacionalmente esses dados para tentar detectar alguma coisa de interesse (que pode ser uma face humana, uma arma, uma fruta estragada em uma esteira de transporte, ou mesmo - como no seu domínio de problema - uma pessoa nua). E essas formas utilizam conceitos da estatística.

### Usando Histograma de Cores

Mencionaram em comentários o uso de histogramas. Um [histograma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histograma) é basicamente uma contagem de ocorrências de algo, apresentado graficamente como forma de ilustrar uma distribuição de frequências. Por exemplo, a reputação no SOpt também é mostrada na forma de um gráfico, em que o eixo vertical apresenta as contagens (frequências) de reputação ganha e o eixo horizontal os intervalos discretos de contabilização (cada dia do mês):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Observação: Estou usando a sua reputação apenas para fins de ilustração.
>   Essa informação é publicamente disponível [no seu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters?tab=reputation&sort=graph) e também no perfil de qualquer outro usuário do SOpt.

Um histograma de cores contabiliza a partir de uma imagem o número de pixels que ocorrem (a frequência, no eixo vertical) para cada valor discreto de cor (no eixo horizontal, e geralmente em uma escala de valores reais entre 0,0 e 1,0 ou inteiros entre 0 e 255). Porém, o que se trata como "cor" pode variar dependendo de algumas escolhas: pode-se contabilizar cada valor RGB (vermelho, verde e azul) separadamente, ou contabilizar o valor de brilho (tom de cinza) como um todo (para entender o que eu quero dizer como "como um todo", leia [esta minha outra resposta aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82354/edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-imagens-utilizando-opencv-sem-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-prontas/83606#83606)), ou mesmo contabilizar apenas a [matiz (hue, em inglês)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matiz_(cor)) de cor se o sistema usado for o [HSV](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV) ao invés do RGB (forma mais comum em problemas como o seu, pois se deseja tratar a cor como um único valor).

A figura a seguir, reproduzida [deste site](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1751373), ilustra o uso de histogramas de cor para analisar uma imagem de um carro. Observe que ela apresenta quatro histogramas: um para a contagem de pixels em vermelho (R), um para a contagem de pixels em verde (G) e um para a contagem de pixels em azul (B), no canto direito superior; e um no canto direito inferior para a contagem dos pixels na escala de brilho (tons de cinza). Entendendo como funciona um histograma, dá pra olhar para o gráfico mais abaixo (de contagem na escala de brilho) pra perceber que a foto é razoavelmente mais clara do que escura, já que há uma maior concentração (uma maior ocorrência) de pixels mais claros do que escuros (há barras verticais mais altas no lado direito, com valores mais próximos de 255, do que no lado esquerdo, com valores mais próximos do 0). Não é a toa que esse tipo de ferramenta é muito utilizada por fotógrafos, uma vez que permite perceber como está a iluminação de uma foto (mais detalhes sobre esse aspecto [neste ótimo artigo](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/pt-br/tutoriais/histograms1.htm)).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E como esse gráfico pode ser utilizado para detectar algo? Bom, tal contabilização é uma distribuição de frequências e como tal pode ser usada para calcular a probabilidade de ocorrência de um pixel (tomado aleatoriamente) com determinada cor/valor *naquela imagem específica* para a qual o histograma foi calculado. Apesar de o carro ser escuro na imagem ilustrada anteriormente, grande parte dos pixels são consideravelmente mais claros devido à parede, ao chão, e até mesmo aos reflexos de luz no teto do carro (que está mais claro do que é realmente). Assim, sorteando-se um pixel aleatoriamente nessa imagem, a probabilidade de ele não ser do carro é bem grande, condizente com o que ilustra o histograma de cores da imagem.

As probabilidades de cada cor/valor são calculadas normalizando essa contagem pelo total de pixels na imagem (ilustrativamente equivalente a "empilhar" as barras, conforme demonstra a figura a seguir).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa imagem é de um artigo da revista [SERVO Magazine (edição 2007, página 37)](http://newplans.net/RDB/Servo%20Magazine%20-%202007-03.pdf) que explica como funciona o algoritmo de rastreamento de faces CamShift do OpenCV. A ideia essencial é que, tendo-se uma imagem de exemplo de uma face (a região inicial da face a ser rastreada no CamShift), pode-se calcular o histograma de cores para ela e então usar esses valores de probabilidas para calcular *em uma nova imagem* a probabilidade de cada pixel ser ou não de uma face. Quando uma região tem mais pixels vizinhos com maior probabilidade de individualmente serem de uma face, a probabilidade de toda a região aumenta, indicando que ali provavelmente há uma face.

Esse mesmo raciocínio pode ser utilizado para a detecção de qualquer objeto de interesse, desde que você tenha calculado o histograma de cores para uma imagem representativa do que quer detectar (ou seja, mesmo se alguém não gostar de fotos de pessoas nuas, ainda assim vai precisar utilizá-las! hehehe). Note, entretanto, que o que esse algoritmo bem simples devolve é a probabilidade de uma região, a partir das probabilidades de cada pixel individual, ser ou não o objeto de interesse. Espera-se que o algoritmo acerte batante, mas ele pode errar, pois essa probabilidade nunca é 100%.

### Aprendizado de máquina

Também mencionaram em comentários a ideia de utilizar aprendizado (ou aprendizagem) computacional. Essa área da Inteligência Artificial também usa muitos métodos da estátistica. Para entender a ideia principal por trás da classificação de dados, aconselho ler [esta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40149/73) (porque já está tudo lá e não vejo sentido em repetir aqui). Ela acaba focando em um algoritmo específico (SVM), mas o início dá uma ideia geral do processo de classificação.

De qualquer forma, o princípio da coisa é:

1. A partir de imagens de exemplo do que se deseja detectar/classificar, são extraídas características importantes. No seu caso, provavelmente envolve cor, mas em outros problemas podem envolver bordas, gradientes, etc.
2. Essas características são utilizadas para treinar um classificador, que então "aprende" como separar dois grupos (por exemplo, é nude, não é nude) a partir dos dados.
3. Esse classificador é então utilizado com dados do mundo real (novos dados, não incluidos na base de treinamento) para de fato classificar a nova imagem.

Um algoritmo para detecção de objetos em imagens que usa aprendizado de máquinas e é bastante popular e robusto é o *Haar Cascade*. Eu já expliquei brevemente como ele funciona [nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12748/73), mas uma distinção importante é que você precisa fornecer exemplos de imagens positivas (que contém o objeto de interesse) e negativas (que não contém o objeto de interesse). Ele tem implementação pronta em OpenCV para detectar faces, olhos, nariz e boca, mas que você pode usar as funções básicas para detectar qualquer coisa ([até mesmo uma banana](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html)). Ele usa como características de treinamento a variação de iluminação de acordo com diferentes "janelas de filtro" (as tais *haar features*), então ele é robusto para detectar objetos porque usa não apenas as cores/valores de iluminação mas também as direções de variação que decorrem essencialmente das bordas. Não sei se ele é ou já foi usado para detectar nudez, pois talvez adicione complexidade desnecessária das inúmeras possíveis variações de postura humana. Mas fica a dica.

### Concluindo

Como você vai perceber nos exemplos ilustrados nas respostas que eu cito anteriormente, sempre há a possibilidade de erros. Talvez porque realmente existam exemplos do mundo real que são *outliers* (algo como "fora da curva"), ou porque ocorram erros naturais de medição (no caso do processamento de imagens digitais, variações de iluminação, oclusão parcial por outros objetos, e variações na rotação ou na escala são dificuldades bem significativas).

Eu realmente não conheço muito desse domínio de problema específico para saber o que é mais usado. Porém, a biblioteca que você usa é baseada em outra em Javascript que por sua vez é baseada [neste artigo](https://be82ac79-a-aff4c786-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/dcs.upd.edu.ph/csp-proceedings/Home/pcsc-2005/AI4.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crCAUrc7JgWMrbz9wpg3C5LLDwCcelD8X2x7oM5gAP4wKhEZ1qNfsClkYIMf75zu_Qn-_f2Iuuno0db3WLdhyx13L-TX4tgTZhgPR4nXZzNG-YCTqjRcimSRIfislLGXjXp5B89L5NJOB9Bqkmrfzqa0059blGZKLs7TbrcMGJnIzk-72WcuudjXu3w1uKaavDy1LhAMbvPEf1t-DfiFbWw80EyUNLuRlZ_oMqjUs1wpmIjcFE%3D&attredirects=0) (também já mencionado em comentários). E esse trabalho propõe utilizar essencialmente um modelo de cor de pele (com imagens de exemplo sob diferentes iluminações), considerando os valores RGB normalizados e a proximidade dos pixels (regiões), porque argumenta que essa é a forma mais comum e factível. Essencialmente, ela o faz de uma forma similar à que eu expliquei anteriormente e usada pelo CamShift do OpenCV. Pelo que o artigo menciona, há configurações de sensibilidade que podem ser alteradas, de forma a permitir um ajuste fino pelo usuário (não sei se a biblioteca fornece acesso a isso, mas vale a pena você investigar já que pode lhe ser útil).

Segundo os testes relatados no artigo, eles obtiveram uma taxa de acurácia em torno de 96,29%. É bem alta, mas veja como não é sempre acertiva. Ainda há uma taxa de 6,76% de falsos positivos (como o caso da sua imagem).

De forma geral, qualquer algoritmo desse tipo vai ter uma margem de acertos e você precisa saber trabalhar com ela. Acima de 90% é uma margem realmente muito boa, e nós não devemos desmerecer o resultado porque ele erra em uma imagem como a que você usou, em que a cor do vestido realmente se confunde com a pele humana.

**Alternativas**

Em um domínio como o seu, em que eu presumo se intenciona evitar que crianças ou pessoas facilmente ofendidas acessem imagens com nús, é muito melhor ter falsos positivos (imagens que não são de nús, mas que foram classificadas como tal) do que ter falsos negativos (imagens que são de nús, mas não foram classificadas como tal). Se o seu algoritmo erra de forma favorável ao uso intencionado, não necessariamente você tem um problema ai, e tais imagens podem ser tratadas em casos excepcionais. Você pode, por exemplo, enviar imagens classificadas como nús para uma avaliação humana posterior (uma espécie de moderador) que vai então liberar ou não tais imagens manualmente. Ou você pode passar só essas imagens por um novo classificador, que usa então outras variáveis (tal como o nome do arquivo, seu tamanho, ou o número de acessos - como alguém já sugeriu até mesmo em comentário).

A inteligência Artificial ainda é muito limitada em comparação ao que o ser humano é capaz de fazer. Então, uma alternativa é justamente você utilizar humanos para fazer tal classificação. Imagina que você poderia construir um sistema que envia fotos para outros usuários avaliadores cadastrados (que não são os usuários principais do seu sistema), que são pagos por foto para apenas classificar como pornográfica ou não. Os valores pagos por foto são pequenos, de forma que você pode enviar a mesma foto para três desses avaliadores, por exemplo, para ter uma resposta "melhor de três" a um custo baixo. Tais avaliadores se interessariam em fazer esse trabalho porque ele é simplesmente trivial, e mesmo pagando pouco por foto talvez eles possam receber um bom salário fazendo muitas dessas classificações em um dia.

Essa solução parece algo inconcebível? Bom, ela já existe: vide o [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome), que fornece uma plataforma para contratar esse tipo de serviço, e a [Descriptive Camera](http://mattrichardson.com/Descriptive-Camera/), que usa *crowd sourcing* dessa mesma forma para imprimir uma descrição da cena ao invés de uma imagem.

Essa solução parece algo com potencial pra fazer o mal? Sim, tanto que é algo sendo amplamente discutido do ponto de vista ético (imagine um país contratando gente do outro lado do mundo para identificar cidadãos em protestos, apenas para citar um exemplo).

Comment: Não sou o autor da pergunta, mas sua resposta é praticamente um artigo sobre o tema! +1

Comment: Obrigado @DiegoFelipe. :)

Comment: Só para zuar um pouco: O printerest precisa usar esse algorítimo urgentemente.

Comment: @LuizVieira Só passei aqui atrasado pra parabenizar pela resposta. Foi uma leitura muito impressionante!

Comment: Fico feliz que você gostou, @ArturoTemplário. :)

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1

Comment: O primeiro link de sua resposta não está funcionando.

Comment: @AndréFilipe Obrigado por avisar. Eu editei e coloquei um novo link para o mesmo artigo.

Comment: Show de bola, a sua resposta está magnifica!

Answer (score 34):

Para complementar a resposta do @LuizVieira no quesito Machine Learning para classificar imagens.

Em Machine Learning, em primeiro lugar, você precisará de um grande número de imagens previamente classificadas por um humano em "nudez" e "não nudez".

Os algoritmos de redes neurais e principalmente `deep learning` são atualmente os mais utilizados para classificação de imagens. Inclusive o Google, recentemente abriu o código de um software p/ rodar algorimos desse tipo, o TensorFlow. No blog de pesquisa deles, tem um [tutorial bem legal](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com.br/2015/12/how-to-classify-images-with-tensorflow.html) sobre como classificar imagens.

A vantagem do Deep Learning, e o que o tornou tão popular atualmente, é que ao invés do que o que o Luiz mencionou:

> A partir de imagens de exemplo do que se deseja detectar/classificar,
>   são extraídas características importantes. No seu caso, provavelmente
>   envolve cor, mas em outros problemas podem envolver bordas,
>   gradientes, etc.

**Não é necessário que um humano extraia essas características importantes.** O único input desses algoritmo são as cores (r,g,b) de cada pixel da imagem (existe antes uma padronização p/ que todas imagens tenham o mesmo tamanho). O próprio algoritmo consegue criar "características" (conjunto de combinações dos pixels) que em seguida podem ser utilizadas para classificar novas imagens sem interferência humana.

**Update**: Recentemente o Google lançou uma [api de visão](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) que parece muito interessante. O preço é no máximo 0.0025$ por imagem para prever conteúdo explícito.

Comment: +1 Ótimo e sucinto complemento. :)

Comment: ótimo complemento, belas referências...