# Existe algum framework de reconhecimento de objetos para Android?

Tags: java, android, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Gostaria de saber se vocês tem conhecimento e se existe um framework de reconhecimento de objetos, pessoas, enfim, coisas, pronto para ser utilizado no Android.

É semelhante a ideia do aplicativo **Google Goggles** e o reconhecimento de pessoas no Facebook para marcar elas em determinada foto.

Se houver disponibilidade sugiro que não apenas recomendem essa ferramenta, mas também detalhem mais a resposta com documentação e exemplo de utilização, para que o conteúdo seja mais rico.

Comment: Tem algum objeto especifico que vc queira reconhecer?

Comment: Preciso que reconheça animais, porém levando em consideração cor, manchas, etc. O usuário vai tirar a foto e irá ser comparado com os já cadastrados no banco de dados.

Comment: O assunto é muito amplo, porem vc pode usar o SimpleCV é um framework que implementa o OpenCV e outras bibliotecas que dão suporte a Computação Visual, assim vc pode criar um servidor e fazer o reconhecimento dos animas no servidor e mandar o resultado para o seu App, acredito eu que se vc salvar as imagens no smarthphone localmente e deixar para fazer todo o processamento local vai ficar muito pesado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, irei pesquisar sobre ele.

Comment: O reconhecimento de objetos é relativamente tranquilo porque eles têm uma configuração de forma bem definida. Vc pode usar o OpenCV, como o colega @DenerCarvalho já mencionou. Aqui tem um tutorial bacana de um algoritmo importante da área: http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

Comment: O reconhecimento de faces também é factível, principalmente em ambientes controlados (em que vc pede pro usuário posicionar a face adequadamente). Na documentação do OpenCV também tem exemplos: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

Comment: Agora, reconhecer animais vai ser bem difícil. Primeiramente porque não há como você controlar como será a exposição (não adianta pedir pra um cachorro olhar fixamente para a câmera e não girar a cabeça, por exemplo). Além disso, a variação de forma e cor é enorme.

Comment: Espero que as dicas sejam úteis. De todas as formas, também acho que a pergunta está muito ampla (apesar de ser um assunto interessantíssimo).

Comment: Isso msm Luiz, não a como controlar a exposição, ele precisaria de um algoritmo poderoso que seria capaz de detectar os animais em vários ângulos, mas mesmo assim surgi mais obstáculos, no caso de pássaros, o algoritmo identificaria de forma genérica os pássaros e não saberia dizer qual espécie é, por exemplo diferenciar um pombo de uma andorinha. Creio eu que com implementação de alguma rede neural isso seria possível, porem pode haver outras maneiras de chegar aos resultados desejados que eu desconheço.

Comment: Agradeço muito pelos comentários, me ajudaram bastante a ter uma ideia de como fazer, imaginaria que com os animais não seria fácil ainda mais que não conheço sobre redes neurais no momento.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Deep Learning tem sido utilizado mesmo pra esse tipo de detecção mais sutil (digamos). :) Um colega deu esta resposta com algumas dicas de como pesquisar (e nela tem um link de um tutorial do Google que pode ser útil): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104778/73

Answer (score 1):

Para reconhecer objectos e um pouco complicado mas a bem pouco tempo a Google disponibilizou num dos updates do Google Play services a Mobile Vision API em que algumas das ferramentas contem mecanismos detecção de caras de pessoas, se estão sorrindo, o nivel do sorriso e características únicas dessa pessoa.

Veja a documentação oficial [aqui](https://developers.google.com/vision/)

Comment: Find objects in photos and video, using real-time on-device vision technology. Fonte: Google. Então acredito que possa servir aqui também, irei pesquisar sobre, valeu.