# Contar quantos pixels de uma cor tem a imagem

Tags: c#, winforms, imagem, processamento-de-imagens, picturebox

Estou trabalhando em uma solução para estúdios de tatuagem.Gostaria de saber como seria possível determinar quantos *pixels* de uma determinada cor existe na imagem inserida na `pictureBox1`.

[Nesta imagem, por exemplo, seria possível contabilizar apenas o diamante,ou seja, sem contar com o espaço em branco? ou então contar apenas o espaço em branco(pois assim seria possível fazer uma subtração no valor da área total)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQsiT.jpg)

Além disso mostrar o resultado da contagem em uma `textbox`.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 form = new Form2();

        form.Show();
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.Filter = "jpg|*.jpg|png|*.png";
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            form.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = file.FileName;
            var count = 0;
            var searchColor = Color.FromName("SlateBlue");
            for (var x = 0; x < form.pictureBox1.Image.Width; x++)
            {
                for (var y = 0; y < form.pictureBox1.Image.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = form.pictureBox1.Image.GetPixel(x, y);
                    if (pixelColor == searchColor)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Não deu certo. Ele não aceita ".GetPixel"

Comment: Gente, muito obrigado, aqui estão mais detalhes: Eu precisaria de apertar um botão que contaria quantos pixels existem do desenho, ou seja sem o fundo, não sendo necessário definir a cor, apenas sem contar com o fundo.Solicitem mais detalhes conforme necessário. Obg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> EDIÇÃO: Surgiu outra pergunta com um problema similar, mas utilizando
>   Java. Então eu essencialmente traduzi o código que criei aqui (e até
>   usei o mesmo exemplo). Se por um acaso algum leitor eventualmente
>   precisar de uma solução também na linguagem Java, por favor
>   referenciar [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107633/73).

Bom, já que a sua imagem não é capturada do mundo real (um detalhe importantíssimo que você não havia colocado na pergunta original), é muito mais simples usar um método como a [limiarização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) para fazer o trabalho automaticamente. A limiarização (*thresholding* em inglês) é um processo em que você transforma uma imagem qualquer em uma imagem binária (contendo apenas duas cores) substituindo todos os pixels na imagem original por uma das cores binárias dependendo de seu brilho ser maior ou menor do que um limiar definido.

Como no seu caso a região da tatuagem é muito distinta do fundo, um valor de limiar médio (`0,5`) é suficiente para um resultado interessante. Mas note que você pode precisar ajustá-lo para um efeito melhor em outras imagens. A comparação é efetuada com o brilho na imagem, e quanto menor o brilho mais próxima a cor é do preto (por isso o código só contabiliza os pixels em que o brilho for *menor* do que o limiar).

Eis um programa de exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Teste
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            file.Filter = "jpg|*.jpg|png|*.png";
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = file.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var limiar = 0.5;

            var count = 0;
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

            for (var x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
            {
                for (var y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = img.GetPixel(x, y);
                    if (pixelColor.GetBrightness() < limiar)
                    {
                        count++;
                        img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                    }
                }
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = img;

            var percent = ((float) count / (img.Width * img.Height)) * 100;
            label1.Text = String.Format("A tattoo contém {0:d} pixels (ou seja, uma área equivalente a {1:f}%)", count, percent);
        }
    }
}
```

A tela inicial tem a Picture Box, dois botões (um para carregar a imagem e exibí-la e outro para processá-la) e um label para apresentar o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após processar, o código não só contabiliza os pixels (e também a porcentagem, um valor mais efetivamente útil porque é normalizado de forma independente às dimensões da imagem) como também troca os pixels da tatuagem para vermelho pra efetivamente demonstrar o que foi calculado. Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação: note que o processamento usa a classe `Bitmap` e não o Picture Box para acessar os pixels brutos.

Comment: muito obrigado cara!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Como a pergunta não tem detalhes, responderei sem detalhes. Seria alguma mais ou menos assim.

```
var count = 0;
var searchColor = Color.FromName("SlateBlue");
for (var x = 0; x < pictureBox1.Image.Width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < pictureBox1.Image.Height; y++) {
        Color pixelColor = pictureBox1.Image.GetPixel(x, y);
        if (pixelColor == searchColor) count++;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Drawing/PixelCount.cs).

Comment: Eu sugeriria adicionar à resposta alguma coisa sobre normalizar a saída. Como as imagens podem ter tamanhos distintos (tá, o AP não menciona nada, mas é bem provável que ele não consiga garantir o mesmo tamanho e foco de imagens de tatuagens), deve fazer mais sentido retornar algo como a porcentagem da área com a cor em relação à área total da imagem do que diretamente uma contagem. :)

Comment: Eu não domino tanto o assunto e talvez você conseguiria dar uma resposta melhor. Posso até ajudar c/ o C# se for preciso. Eu só sei que, ingenuamente, teria que dar uma margem de tolerância da cor e não pegar tão exato. A porcentagem é fácil, eu poderia até colocar, é que é matemática básica. Queria que ele falasse algo para direcionar melhor.

Comment: Gente, muito obrigado, aqui estão mais detalhes: Eu precisaria de apertar  um botão que contaria quantos pixels existem do desenho, ou seja sem o fundo, não sendo necessário definir a cor, apenas sem contar com o fundo.

Comment: Se  forem necessários mais detalhes, estarei aqui

Comment: @bigown, a resposta tá otima com base no que o AP forneceu. E a tal normalização é mesmo matemática básica no sentido que colocou. :)

Comment: @EmanuelBorges, nesse caso talvez fosse mais interessante você clicar na cor que deseja contabilizar, capturar o pixel clicado e usá-lo como `searchColor` no algoritmo desta resposta. Diferenciar objeto de fundo automaticamente não é tarefa tão trivial. Se o fundo for "pele", talvez essa outra pergunta te dê uma ideia das dificuldades envolvidas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104656/algoritmo-para-detectar-nudez-com-boa-precis%C3%A3o

Comment: @EmanuelBorges pra mim ficou até mais confuso agora :) Não sei se o Luiz entendeu melhor já que ele domina mais o assunto.

Comment: @EmanuelBorges: edite a pergunta e adicione detalhes do problema. Se possível, poste principalmente uma imagem de exemplo, e um diagrama detalhando qual é a região exata que você quer contabilizar.

Comment: @LuizVieira:@EmanuelBorges, nesse caso talvez fosse mais interessante você clicar na cor que deseja contabilizar, capturar o pixel clicado e usá-lo como searchColor no algoritmo desta resposta. Diferenciar objeto de fundo automaticamente não é tarefa tão trivial. Se o fundo for "pele", talvez essa outra pergunta te dê uma ideia das dificuldades envolvidas. Nesse caso, como o faria no código?

Comment: oh o @bigown mandando ver nas respostas!

Comment: Ok, eu dei uma nova resposta, baseada na ideia desta resposta do @bigown e nas novas edições da questão. :)