# Como criar um Bitmap a partir de um Color[][]?

Tags: c#

Precisei transformar um Bitmap em Color[][] para aplicar alguns algoritmos e preciso recriar o bitmap. Tem uma maneira fácil de fazer isso?

Para transformar o bitmap em Color[][] eu fiz o que tá abaixo. Tem uma maneira mais fácil?

```
    public Color[][] GetPixels(Bitmap b1)
    {
        int hight = b1.Height;
        int width = b1.Width;

        Color[][] colorMatrix = new Color[width][];
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            colorMatrix[i] = new Color[hight];
            for (int j = 0; j < hight; j++)
            {
                colorMatrix[i][j] = b1.GetPixel(i, j);
            }
        }
        return colorMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: Vc pode criar um bitmap novo (classe `Bitmap` com as dimensões do array) e então percorrer os elementos do array para definir cada pixel do bitmap com o valor dado usando o método `SetPixel`. Você pode tentar inferir um exemplo a partir [desta minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105794/73) em uma outra pergunta. Eu não vou responder porque não sei, de fato, se essa é a melhor forma em C#. Talvez tenha algum construtor apropriado. Vale verificar.

Comment: Isso que você disse é o que to fazendo aqui. Vou continuar procurando se existe uma maneira mais fácil e se encontrar eu coloco aqui.

Comment: Não existe nenhum construtor de Bitmap que aceite uma matriz bidimensional de Color, logo a forma que você está fazendo é a única possível...percorrer um a um dentro de 2 loops!

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não há um construtor ou método de `Bitmap` que aceita mesmo um array bidimensional (como foi notado nos comentários). A solução dada nos comentários de Luiz Vieira seria um método adequado. Algo assim *(não testado!)*:

```cs
public Bitmap SetPixels(Color[][] colors)
{
    int hight = colors.GetLength(1);
    int width = colors.GetLength(0);

    Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        colorMatrix[i] = new Color[hight];
        for (int j = 0; j < hight; j++)
        {
            b1.SetPixel(i,j,colors[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return b1;
}
```