# Como saber quantos pixels "pretos" tem em uma letra x, usando uma fonte x?

Tags: c#

A pergunta já diz tudo, na maneira que eu estava fazendo, eu escrevia vários caracteres, printava e colocava o programa pra contar de uma em uma :/

Comment: existe um método DrawString() na classe Graphics que dá para desenhar texto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ícaro, desenvolvi a seguinte solução com base em um Bitmap onde é escrito um texto em pixels pretos e logo após é efetuada uma varredura na mesma imagem contando os pixels pretos e brancos.

Segue o código:

```
//Instanciação do Bitmap (por padrão todos os pixels são brancos)
var bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);

//Instanciação da fonte para impressão do(s) caracter(es) no Bitmap
var fonte = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 24);

//Um novo objeto do tipo Graphics é gerado a partir do Bitmap
var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
//Logo após imprimimos o texto através do objeto Graphics 
g.DrawString("X", fonte, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
//Que por sua vez ao chamar Flush() grava os dados no Bitmap original.
g.Flush();

int count_black = 0, count_white = 0;

//Efetuamos a varredura pixel a pixel no Bitmap e verificamos quais pixels são brancos ou pretos e incrementamos o contador.
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; ++y)
    {
        var pxl_color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb();

        if (pxl_color == Color.Black.ToArgb()) ++count_black; 
        else ++count_white;
    }
}

//Mostramos o resultado da varredura.
MessageBox.Show(count_black.ToString() + " pixels pretos e " + count_white.ToString() + " pixels brancos foram encontrados.");
```

O código foi testado em projeto Windows Forms.

Comment: Note que incrementei o contador de pixels brancos em "else" pois já sabia previamente que não haviam pixels de outras cores no Bitmap.

Comment: CARAAAA VOCÊE É UM DEEUUUUSSS!!! EXATAMENTE O QUE EU QUERIA ::o:o:o:o:o:o:o

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não diz exatamente tudo. Vc menciona a fonte da letra, de forma que eu imaginei que a sua necessidade envolve saber as *dimensões* de um texto para fazer algo a respeito, e não necessariamente contar os pixels no texto. Mas posso estar enganado. Se a sua necessidade é realmente contar os pixels, a resposta do colega @BrunoBermann é o caminho (e tem também [essa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105693/73) que pode ser útil). Caso contrário, o que você precisa é utilizar as métricas da fonte (com a ajuda do método [`Graphics.MeasureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Eis um exemplo (baseado no exemplo que está na documentação) que calcula as dimensões do texto apenas para desenhar um retângulo vermelho à sua volta:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TesteSOPT
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Cria a string a ser desenhada
            String drawString = "Olá Mundo!";

            // Cria a fonte e o brush de pintura
            Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 42);
            SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            // Esse é o ponto a partir de onde o texto vai ser pintado (canto esquerdo-superior).
            Point drawPoint = new Point(10, 20);

            // Pinta o texto na janela (Form1).
            e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);

            // Desenha um retângulo vermelho ao redor do texto, usando as métricas de fonte
            rectAround(drawPoint, drawFont, drawString, e.Graphics);

        }

        private void rectAround(Point drawPoint, Font drawFont, string drawString, Graphics g  )
        {
            Size textSize = g.MeasureString(drawString, drawFont).ToSize();
            Console.WriteLine(textSize);

            Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 5);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(drawPoint, textSize);

            g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Esse código produz a seguinte saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom, mas o amigo lá fez exatamente o que eu queria o/!!!