# O que é deep learning?

Tags: terminologia, aprendizagem-de-máquina, deep-learning

Lendo uma das respostas, sobre [Algoritmo para detectar nudez com boa precisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104656/algoritmo-para-detectar-nudez-com-boa-precis%C3%A3o/104767#104767), eu vi que um termo que é muito citado e referido é *Deep Learning*. Para mim, traduzindo Aprendizagem Profunda, não fez muito sentido.

- O que é *Deep Learning*?
- Onde, o que ou quem estuda *Deep Learning*?
- No que *Deep Learning* influencia?

Comment: Relacionado? [O que é machine learning ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113343)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Deep learning` está associado a inteligencia artificial e principalmente aliado a [redes neurais](https://www.tecmundo.com.br/programacao/2754-o-que-sao-redes-neurais-.htm), o objetivo de uma rede neural é aprender e reconhecer padrões, para isso faz o uso de vários neurônios, que formam uma rede, como a imagem a seguir[image: neurônio artificial].

Os valores de W representam o input de dados em um neurônio e o output dele será ligado em outros neurônios, cada neurônio tem um "peso" que é chamado de limiar e que define a função feita por ele.

Importante apontar que elas são redes não supervisionadas, elas aprendem sozinhas sem a supervisão humana.

As máquinas inspiradas em Deep Learning conseguem aprender abstrações complexas dos dados através de um processo de aprendizagem hierárquica muito similar ao que ocorre no cérebro humano – sobretudo no córtex visual.

[image: Rede neural]

Logo uma rede é montada e os neurônios nas camadas interiores são responsáveis por identificar pequenos padrões em algo maior, como por exemplo na verificação do caracter "7", uma parte da rede reconhece os ângulos e direções de cada pixel na imagem.

No seu caso citado, de pornografia, a rede neural é capaz de identificar pequenos padrões e que se somados podem afirmar que, por exemplo, o que aparece na imagem é um pênis.
Existem várias técnicas de avaliação da rede neural, só creio que isso está um pouco fora do escopo da sua pergunta, entretanto sugiro a leitura sobre [Perceptron](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) e [Backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation).

Deep learning pode ter o input de várias coisas, principalmente dados não estruturados e pode ser usada para reconhecimento de fotos, som, vídeos, textos e outros.

Para mais detalhes sobre Deep learning eu sugiro [essa](http://www.falandoti.com/ao-fundo-da-inteligencia-artificial-o-que-e-deep-learning/) postagem.

Comment: Bem legal cara, obrigado pelo comentario ;)

Comment: Essa é uma área bem complexa e muito lógica, assim que se começa a estudar não da pra parar, hahahh

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1

Answer (score 12):

**Deep Learning** são redes neurais artificiais com muitas camadas. Essas camadas quando combinadas de forma inteligente resultaram em grandes avanços na área de inteligência artificial.

Normalmente em problemas de aprendizado de máquina é necessário que um ser humano determine *features* que descrevem um conjunto de dados. Uma *feature* é, por exemplo, o que o Luiz descreve sobre os histogramas de cores [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104767/6036). A grande vantagem do **Deep Learning** é a habilidade desses modelos extraírem *features* dos dados crus, sem a necessidade de uma intervenção humana.

Apesar de modelos simples como um Multilayer Perceptron com 3 camadas já serem considerados como **Deep Learning**, não está aí o seu grande sucesso. O que realmente tem revolucionado esse campo são arquiteturas de redes mais avançadas como:

- Redes Neurais convolucionais: para reconhecimento de imagens. Exemplo: [Indentificação de nomes de ruas no Google Street View](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-google-maps-with-deep-learning.html)
- Redes Neurais Recorrentes (como LSTM's e GRU's): para sequências em geral (textos e sons). Exemplo: [Google Tradutor](https://research.googleblog.com/2016/11/zero-shot-translation-with-googles.html)
- Combinações de redes convolucionais e recorrentes: para processamento de vídeos. Exemplo: [Thumbnails de vídeos do YouTube](https://research.googleblog.com/2015/10/improving-youtube-video-thumbnails-with.html)
- Redes Neurais com atenção que parecem ser menos específicas. [Ler aqui](http://distill.pub/2016/augmented-rnns/)

E muitas outras que surgem todos os meses. 
Pelos exemplos que mostrei, dá pra ver o quanto o Google usa Deep Learning em seus projetos de pesquisa, mas não é o único. Basta entrar no site do grupo de pesquisa de outras grandes empresas de tecnologia:

- [Facebook](https://research.fb.com/publications/densely-connected-convolutional-networks/)
- [Baidu](http://research.baidu.com/deep-voice-2-multi-speaker-neural-text-speech/)

E muitos outros.

Deep learning está influenciando muito a área de visão computacional. Não tem uma empresa de carros autônomos, por exemplo, que não use deep-learning como tecnologia central do software de direção automatizada.

Atualmente, o melhor framework para começar a mexer com Deep Learning é o `keras`. Tanto para [python](https://github.com/fchollet/keras) quanto para [R](https://github.com/rstudio/keras).

Vale lembrar que Deep Learning pode ser usado em todas as formas de aprendizado de máquina: não supervisionado, supervisionado e aprendizado por reforço.