# Ajuda processamento de imagem (remoção de fundo)

Tags: java, processamento-de-imagens

preciso criar um código para realizar o processamento de frames de um vídeo. No caso o programa irá varrer os pixels da imagem e analisará as cores dos pixels e caso encontre cores próximas à cor inicialmente definida, deve substituir ela, por exemplo, por um verde chroma key (substituir o fundo).

Gostaria de dicas sobre isso: que biblioteca utilizar, como posso realizar a verificação da cor ser próxima da cor que irei definir (me disseram para usar a banda RGB, porém não me disseram muito especificamente o que fazer).

Se tiverem algum código de exemplo também seria muito útil.

EDIT:

O que não sei realmente é como tratar a imagem.

Meu objetivo é ler todos os pixels da mesma e verificar a cor deles. No caso, quero verificar se os pixels são semelhantes à um tom de laranja que irei escolher, para ser mais específico. Se o programa encontrar um determinado pixel que seja semelhante à este laranja (mais claro, escuro, etc...), deve substituí-lo por um verde estilo chroma key.

Não sei como realizar essa comparação dos pixels. Me recomendaram utilizar a banda RGB de cada pixel para determinar a semelhança do mesmo com o laranja (através de um "limiar" de semelhança). Porém não sei se esta seria a melhor forma de comparar os pixels e nem como realizaria a comparação dos valores RGB para verificar se o pixel encontrado é semelhante ao laranja (está dentro do limiar se semelhança).

Comment: Olá. Esta outra pergunta tem um problema similar (ainda que em C#, mas dá pra ter uma ideia do algoritmo de Limiarização e, quem sabe, te ajuda): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105693/contar-quantos-pixels-de-uma-cor-tem-a-imagem De todas as formas, por favor forneça mais detalhes do seu problema em especial, senão sua pergunta fica muito ampla pois qualquer sugestão é igualmente válida.

Comment: Aliás, parece que você tem dificuldades que vão além do problema de segmentação da imagem. Parece que você não sabe, por exemplo, como acessar os pixels de uma imagem em Java. Se for o caso, eu sugeriria você editar esta pergunta para torná-la mais específica nesse aspecto, e ir abrindo novas perguntas para ter ajudas pontuais e assim construir seu aprendizado mais gradualmente. Uma só pergunta ampla tende a ser fechada como tal. :)

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas Luiz, adicionei algo mais específico à pergunta.

Comment: Bom, eu estou de férias então não tenho um ambiente de desenvolvimento (e mesmo tempo, hehehe) pra postar uma resposta. Mas você pode tirar uma ideia de como se acessa/altera os valores dos pixels em uma imagem usando Java deste código: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Threshold.java.html

Comment: E não se esqueça: se você fornecer na pergunta uma imagem de exemplo dos quadros do vídeo que precisa processar, facilitaria muito alguém te dar respostas mais diretas.

Answer (score 6):

Como eu já havia comentado, [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105693/contar-quantos-pixels-de-uma-cor-tem-a-imagem) tem um problema similar (mas em C#). A solução trivial é usar o processo de limiarização: você varre todos os pixels da imagem e troca pela cor desejada (verde) apenas aqueles pixels que estão abaixo ou acima de um limiar escolhido.

Fiz um programa de exemplo similar ao que está [na minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105794/73) daquela outra pergunta (isto é, basicamente converti aquele código C# pra Java):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Limiar extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel m_oImage;

    private JButton m_oLoadButton;
    private JButton m_oDetectButton;

    private JPanel m_oButtonsPanel;

    final JFileChooser m_oFileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    public Limiar() {
        super("Exemplo de Limiarização");

        m_oImage = new JLabel();
        m_oImage.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        m_oImage.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        add(m_oImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        m_oButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
        m_oButtonsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(m_oButtonsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        m_oButtonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        add(m_oButtonsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        m_oLoadButton = new JButton("Carregar Imagem...");
        m_oLoadButton.addActionListener(this);
        m_oLoadButton.setActionCommand("Load");
        m_oLoadButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        m_oButtonsPanel.add(m_oLoadButton);

        m_oButtonsPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));

        m_oDetectButton = new JButton("Substituir fundo");
        m_oDetectButton.addActionListener(this);
        m_oDetectButton.setActionCommand("Detect");
        m_oDetectButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        m_oButtonsPanel.add(m_oDetectButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getActionCommand().equals("Load")) {

            int iRet = m_oFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

            if (iRet == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File oFile = m_oFileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                BufferedImage oImg;
                ImageIcon oIcon;
                try {
                    oImg = ImageIO.read(new File(oFile.getPath()));
                    oIcon = new ImageIcon(oImg);
                    m_oImage.setIcon(oIcon);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível abrir a imagem selecionada");
                }

            }
        }
        else if (oEvent.getActionCommand().equals("Detect")) {

            final double THRESHOLD = 127.5;

            ImageIcon oIcon = (ImageIcon) m_oImage.getIcon();
            BufferedImage oImg = new BufferedImage(oIcon.getIconWidth(), oIcon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            Graphics2D oGr = oImg.createGraphics();
            oIcon.paintIcon(null, oGr, 0, 0);
            oGr.dispose();

            double dBrightness;
            Color oColor;

            for (int x = 0; x < oImg.getWidth(); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < oImg.getHeight(); y++) {
                    oColor = new Color(oImg.getRGB(x, y));

                    dBrightness = 0.21 * oColor.getRed() + 0.72 * oColor.getGreen()  + 0.07 * oColor.getBlue();
                    if (dBrightness > THRESHOLD) {
                        oImg.setRGB(x, y, Color.GREEN.getRGB());
                    }
                }
            }

            m_oImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(oImg));
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Limiar t = new Limiar();

        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(600,480);
        t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

O resultado (usando a mesma imagem de tatuagem da pergunta citada) é o seguinte (o fundo é trocado para verde, e o resto é mantido inalterado):

Tela após carregar a imagem da tatuagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela após processar a substituição do fundo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Detalhes importantes

1. Lá no código original em C# já havia um método (`getBrightness`) para devolver o brilho (isto é, converter a cor em 3 bandas para escala de cinza). Eu desconheço se há um método para isso em Java (ao menos não encontrei nada na classe `Color`). Por isso, converti eu mesmo (com uma continha que está explicada [nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83606/73)).
2. Os valores de um pixel (seja em RGB ou em tons de cinza) são normalizados em C# como um `float` entre `0.0` e `1.0`. No caso do Java, são valores entre `0.0` e `255.0`. Por isso o limiar inicial escolhido naquele código original era `0.5` e aqui é `127.5`.
3. O caso da outra pergunta era mais simples porque as imagens eram mais padronizadas com fundo mais claro do que o restante (sempre tinham fundo branco). Você não oferece detalhes sobre o vídeo que está processando (nem sequer um exemplo! tsc, tsc, tsc), mas eu imagino que o fundo não vai ter um padrão muito simples. Você certamente vai precisar alterar o valor do limiar para fazer alguns testes. E se o fundo for mais escuro do que o restante da imagem, você vai também precisar trocar o operador de comparação do brilho de `>` para `<` (para detectar e trocar apenas o que for mais escuro - lembre-se que quanto mais próximo do `0`, mais escuro o pixel é). Por exemplo, o processamento desse famoso meme a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai resultar assim com o código atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E assim, se você apenas trocar o operador para `<`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como nessa imagem o fundo é mais escuro do que o gato, a troca funciona melhor. Porém, observe como o algoritmo falha ao incluir a gravata e o óculos do gato como parte do "fundo". Em casos como esses, você poderia fazer comparações mais rebuscadas, como verificar se o pixel está em um intervalo de luminosidade, ou se ele se inclui em uma região conexa grande (isto é, se se trata mais provavelmente de um fundo ou não).

4. Alternativamente ao método de limiarização, pode ser possível fazer segmentações estatísticas com análise das probabilidades do histograma de cores (algo similiar ao que eu descrevo [nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104767/73)) ou com o treinamento de uma árvore de decisão. Mas, isso vai depender do seu domínio de problema (e só pra citar mais uma vez, você infelizmente não proveu nenhuma informação sobre isso, apesar dos inúmeros pedidos).
5. Lembre-se que fazer o processamento de segmentação *para cada quadro* de um vídeo vai ser computacionalmente custoso e pode deixar a renderização da saída lenta. Talvez você precise trabalhar para melhorar o desempenho ou repensar o problema.