# Cálculo de área de figuras

Tags: c++, processamento-de-imagens, opencv, cores

Talvez já tenha algo por aqui sobre o assunto, mas não encontrei.
Sou novo na área e gostaria de ajuda para elaborar um algoritmo em C++ para a detecção da área de uma cor pré-determinada em uma figura. Ou seja: o usuário insere apenas a imagem no programa, e o programa retorna para ele a área da cor vermelha, por exemplo (o usuário não escolhe a cor, ela já vai embutida no programa, será sempre a mesma).
Eu gostaria muito da sugestão de um tutorial (ou mais de um) para seguir ou então da instrução de alguém.
Estou utilizando o Visual Studio já com OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, você não forneceu detalhes importantes do seu problema (por exemplo: Que tipo de imagem se trata? A cor vermelha é vermelho puro, ou é um intervalo de tons de vermelho?) e também não ficou claro o que realmente vc quer ao dizer "o programa retorna pra ele a área" (o programa calcula a área em pixels? o programa realça a área com outra cor? etc). Então eu fiz um exemplo simples que pode te ajudar a começar a entender o problema. Ele utiliza operações simples, em que você mesmo procura e altera os valores dos pixels comparando-os a uma cor desejada.

No exemplo do código a seguir, eu procuro pela cor vermelha EXATA (em código BGR - o utilado pelo OpenCV - isso significa (0, 0, 255), porque é 0 para o azul/blue, 0 para o verde/green e 255 para o vermelho/red), conto o número de pixels que têm essa cor e já os substituo por uma outra cor dada (no exemplo, amarelo, para realçar a mudança):

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/**
 * Conta o número de pixels na imagem com a primeira cor e os substitui pela segunda cor.
 * @param oImagem cv::Mat com os dados da imagem colorida.
 * @param oCor cv::Vec3b com os valores BGR dos pixels a serem contados/substituidos.
 * @param oNovaCor cv::Vec3b com os valores BGR para substituir os pixels encontrados.
 * @return Retorna um inteiro com o número de pixels encontrados com a cor dada.
 */
int processaCorExata(Mat &oImagem, Vec3b oCor, Vec3b oNovaCor)
{
    Vec3b oPixel;
    int iPixels = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < oImagem.size().width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < oImagem.size().height; y++)
        {
            oPixel = oImagem.at<Vec3b>(y, x);

            // Checa se o pixel tem EXATAMENTE a mesma cor
            if (oPixel[0] == oCor[0] && oPixel[1] == oCor[1] && oPixel[2] == oCor[2])
            {
                iPixels++; // Contabiliza o pixel
                oImagem.at<Vec3b>(y, x) = oNovaCor; // Substitui pela nova cor dada
            }
        }
    }
    return iPixels;
}

/**
 * Função principal.
 * @param argc Inteiro com o número de argumentos da linha de comando.
 * @param argv Lista de strings com os argumentos da linha de comando.
 * @return Retorna um inteiro com o código de erro ou 0 se encerrado com sucesso.
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Carrega a imagem colorida de exemplo
    Mat oImagem = imread("C:/Temp/rgb.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if (!oImagem.data)
    {
        cout << "Erro carregando a imagem" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Exibe a imagem original em uma janela
    namedWindow("Imagem Original", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Imagem Original", oImagem);

    // Definição das cores
    Vec3b oVermelho(0, 0, 255);
    Vec3b oAmarelo(0, 255, 255);

    // Conta os pixels em vermelho e os substitui por amarelo
    int iPixels = processaCorExata(oImagem, oVermelho, oAmarelo);

    // Calcula a área em vermelho (número de pixels e percentual sobre a área total da imagem)
    int iAreaTotal = oImagem.size().width * oImagem.size().height;
    ostringstream sMsgBuilder;
    sMsgBuilder << "Pixels vermelhos: " << iPixels;
    sMsgBuilder << " (" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << (iPixels / (float)iAreaTotal) * 10.0 << "%)";
    string sMsg = sMsgBuilder.str();

    // Exibe essa informação na saída padrão e também na imagem
    cout << sMsg << endl;

    double dScale = 0.5;
    int iThickness = 3;
    int iFontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX;
    int iBaseline = 0;
    Size oSize = getTextSize(sMsg.c_str(), iFontFace, dScale, iThickness, &iBaseline);
    iBaseline += iThickness;

    Point oPos(iThickness, oImagem.rows - oSize.height - iThickness);
    putText(oImagem, sMsg.c_str(), oPos, FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 1.0, Scalar::all(0));

    // Exibe a imagem processada em uma nova janela
    namedWindow("Imagem Processada", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Imagem Processada", oImagem);

    // Aguarda o usuário fechar as janelas ou pressionar qualquer tecla
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

A imagem de exemplo utilizada nos meus testes é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que após o processamento gera o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**IMPORTANTE**: Observe, entretanto, que esse programa não vai funcionar como esperado para imagens com cores mais distintas (isto é, outros tons de vermelho). Há alternativas, claro, para esses casos. Vc pode tentar fazer limiarizações (veja a função [`threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) do OpenCV), ou gerar vc mesmo máscaras com limiares maiores e usar diretamente a função [`inRange`](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/) do OpenCV (um método mais recomendado do que fazer as manipulações que eu exemplifico no código acima, *caso as imagens do seu domínio de problema realmente sejam mais complexas*).

> P.S.: A lógica é a mesma dessas minhas outras respostas em [C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105794/73) e
>   em [Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107633/73).