# Escala de cinza em Imagens - OPENCV

Tags: c++, processamento-de-imagens, opencv

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Tenho uma imagem .bmp e quero transformá-la em escala de cinza(0-255), através do Opencv com C++(Não quero salvar esta imagem em escala de cinza). Daí, quero percorrer a imagem fazendo o seguinte:

Para cada pixel, se a escala de cinza está entre 0-31, então este pixel pertence à classe 1. Se está entre 32-63 então este pixel pertence à classe 2 ... e assim vai. Teremos assim 8 classes.

Daí eu quero saber quantos pixels fazem parte da classe 1, 2, 3, ... , 8.

Como posso fazer isso? Procurei na documentação do Opencv mas não encontrei algo que me ajude nesse sentido.

Muito Obrigado Pessoal!

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum e tampouco um classificado. O que você já fez? Qual é a sua *dificuldade específica* nesse monte de coisas que vc quer fazer? Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour]. Ah, e procure aqui no site mesmo. Tem muito conteúdo que pode te ajudar. Como esse, por exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82354/edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-imagens-utilizando-opencv-sem-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-prontas

Answer (score 1):

```
Mat img = imread("sua_imagem.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
vector<int> acumulador(8);

for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
        int index = (int)img.at<uchar>(i, j) / 32;
        acumulador[index]++;
    }
```

isso deve resolver o seu problema, o vetor acumulador é de tamanho 8, onde cada posição contem o número de pixels da imagem pertencentes aquela classe.